# Regression to remove consecutive effects

Tags: regression

Suppose I want to know how my observable X depends on Y and on Z. But Y itself depends on Z (e.g. they are correlated). I want to know the effect of Y on X after removing the effect of Z on both X and Y.

What is the right regression procedure for that? - Should I regress Z on X, take the residuals, and regress those on Y?

Like,

```
X = a * Z + e1
e1 = b * Y + e2
```

I know I could do PCA, but I want the first order effect to be coming from Z exactly, the second order effect e2 to be orthogonal to e1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this but it's good to maintain an estimate of the effect of Z on Y as well.  If you regress Y on the residuals of X regressed on Z then you'll get the answer you've asked for.  However, you might be better off just doing the multiple regression of Y on both X and Z.  Try both of those and look at the results.  You'll find it interesting.  If the correlation between X and Z is too high this won't work but then your question doesn't have an answer anyway.